# C++ Running 2 processes at a time

Tags: c++

A C++ question on running 2 processes at a time.

I have a client-server model kind of C++ code. My server will fork for every connection from the client. This is a system that also has a reminder module. This reminder module will need to send an email when, let's say, it counts down from 1000 to 0: when it reaches 0, it will perform its code.

But my server is already running in a while(1) loop. How do I invoke this reminder thing together while not affecting the server listening to connections?

Thanks for all help and suggestions.

Comment: you don't need 2 processes, you need 2 threads, learn the difference between a process and a thread, a process can have multiple threads, if you can go away with using extra threads do not go to more complicated solutions, requiring inter process communication and what not

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for what is commonly know as threads.
Here is an example using Boost.Thread:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <boost/thread.hpp>  
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>  

bool worker_running = true;

void workerFunc() {
    while (worker_running) {
        boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);  

        // do something 

        boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);  
    }
}  

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  
    //before your while loop: 

    boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);  

    //while loop here

    worker_running = false;           
    workerThread.join(); 

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend reading the boost documentation ^_^  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread.html

Comment: @CountMurphy: Shoot, totally forgot to append that link.